# Jquery llamar función en html añadido

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy intentando llamar una función para html añadido con append, por alguna razón el código siguiente no llama la función set_file en el evento onclick del botón:

```
    var maxAppend=0;
    function addRow() {  
          let html = "<tr>" +
            "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='datepicker' value='dd/mm/YYYY' size='6'></td>" +
            "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' size='1'/></td>" +
            "<td><textarea class='form-control' rows='2' cols='25'></textarea></td>" +
            "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' size='1'/></td>" +
            "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' size='1'/></td>" +
            "<td><select class='form-control'><option>Entidad</option></select></td>" +
            "<td><select class='form-control'><option>Tipo</option></select></td>" +
            "<td><button type='button' onclick='set_file("+maxAppend+",1)' id='get_file"+maxAppend+"1' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload' style='float:right;display: inline-block;' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>" +
            "<input type='file' id='my_file"+maxAppend+"1'>" + 
            "<td><button type='button' onclick='set_file("+maxAppend+",2)' id='get_file"+maxAppend+"2' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload' style='float:right;display: inline-block;' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>" +
            "<input type='file' id='my_file"+maxAppend+"2'>" +  
            "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'><span class='fa fa-edit' style='float:right;display: inline-block;' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>" +
            "</tr>";
            $("#table_retentions").append(html);
            maxAppend++;
        }
  function set_file(i,j){
     $('#my_file'+i+j).click();
  }
```

La consola no muestra errores ni warnings, ¿Qué es lo que estará mal?

Comment: En el código que muestras no llamas la función en ningún momento, solo la declaras

Comment: @CamiloGomez en elemento button está la llamada onclick='set_file("+maxAppend+",1)'

Comment: Cierto, no vi eso. Una cosa que noto es que en esa llamada tienes `"+maxAppend+"` como primer argumento. No veo esta variable declarada, pero este argumento es un numero, entonces los + antes y después deben estar causando el problema

Comment: @CamiloGomez es una variable global, la agregué al código, el html que se forma creo que está bien y forma bien la llamada, pero no la ejecuta.

Comment: La llamada a la función `set_file()` se te tiene que estar haciendo correctamente, si le pones un `console.log()` verás que se te está pintando. El problema lo tienes en lo que hace esa función. Con `$('#my_file'+i+j).click();` estás llamando al onclick de unos elementos que no tienen ningún evento **click** asociado, por lo que no ocurre nada. De todas formas creo que te estás complicando mucho la vida para tratar de afectar a un input que pertenezca a la misma fila que el botón que lanza la función. Te recomiendo que mires sobre el selector **this** de JQuery: `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**en tu fila de la tabla. colocalo algo asi**

```
 "<td><button type='button' data-maxapp='+maxAppend+' data-idfuncion='+1+'  id='get_file"+maxAppend+"1' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload' style='float:right;display: inline-block;' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>"
```

**Intenta llamar la funcion de esta manera.**

```
$(document).on('click', '#table_retentions  td  button'  , function() {
var datamaxapp= $('#get_file').data('maxapp');
var dataidfuncion= $('#get_file').data('idfuncion');

    set_file(datamaxapp,dataidfuncion)  
 
});
```

**Para mas informacion consulta**
https://api.jquery.com/on/
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp

**Para contactarme y ayudarte**
http://carloscordova.com/

**Codigo completo**

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
       var maxAppend=0;
    function addRow() {  
          let html = "<tr>" +
            "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='datepicker' value='dd/mm/YYYY' size='6'></td>" +
            "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' size='1'/></td>" +
            "<td><textarea class='form-control' rows='2' cols='25'></textarea></td>" +
            "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' size='1'/></td>" +
            "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' size='1'/></td>" +
            "<td><select class='form-control'><option>Entidad</option></select></td>" +
            "<td><select class='form-control'><option>Tipo</option></select></td>" +
            "<td><button type='button' onclick='set_file("+maxAppend+",1)' id='get_file"+maxAppend+"1' class='btn btn-primary onclick'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload' style='float:right;display: inline-block;' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>" +
            "<td><input type='file' id='my_file"+maxAppend+"1'> </td>" + 
            "<td><button type='button' onclick='set_file("+maxAppend+",2)' id='get_file"+maxAppend+"2' class='btn btn-primary onclick'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload' style='float:right;display: inline-block;' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>" +
            "<td><input type='file' id='my_file"+maxAppend+"2'></td>" +  
            "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'><span class='fa fa-edit' style='float:right;display: inline-block;' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>" +
            "</tr>";
            $("#table_retentions").append(html);
            maxAppend++;
        }
  function set_file(i,j){
     $('#my_file'+i+j).click();
     alert("my_file "+ "  "+i+"  "+j);
  }



  $(document).ready(function() {
     addRow() ;


  });


</script>

<table id="table_retentions"> </table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Carlos, pero me lanza este error: Uncaught ReferenceError: td is not defined

Comment: el problema es el selector, "td > button"

Comment: Revisa que estas haciendo referencia correctamente hacia el selector . o lo puedes cambiar por una clase.

Comment: probé con y sin la clase, pero no hace nada y no muestra ningún error ni warning

Comment: http://carloscordova.com/ mandame mensaje, te ayudo

Comment: te envié uno por tu página

Comment: Lo que yo veo, es que la función set_file no hace nada, sólo captura el evento click del input con id my_file+i+j. Qué se supone que haga?